# How did the tablet become like this?

Tags: medicinal-chemistry

How did the tablet become like this? [image]

There was a gap in the packet, so I'm guessing it reacted with moisture but is it so?

Edit: Composition of 'Tendocare'- Chondroitin Sulfate and Vitamin C tablets.
Ingredients- Lactose, Chondroitin Sulfate sodium, Binder(468), Collagen peptides type 1, Sodium Hyaluronate, Binder(462) Stabilizer(1202),(1205)and(464), Silicon Dioxide, Magnesium Stearate, Sorbic Acid, Emulsifier.
Contains permitted natural colors and flavor. Appropriate overages added.
NUTRACEUTICAL, NOT FOR MEDICINAL USE.

Comment: The post plausible scenario

Comment: A bit hard to say with no indication of the tablet's composition. But, yes, many tablets swell and disintegrate when exposed to moisture.

Comment: @jeffB I've edited my question in response to your comment.

Comment: The most likely possibilities are mechanical crushing or expansion due to absorption of water vapor.